# How to secure key and authentication files on GitLab

Tags: gitlab, cloud, devops, pipeline, cicd

I possess a key for accessing my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project, along with SSH keys within the project. I need to incorporate them into my CI/CD pipeline, but it's not secure to simply push them directly to GitLab.

I dont know if its possible with terraform cloud ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a highly secure solution, then you should use a dedicated secrets management service such as Google Cloud KMS or HashiCorp Vault. If you are on a budget or do not need the highest level of security, then you can store your GCP keys as encrypted variables in the Terraform Cloud workspace.